# Bad format of XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

i have this XSL:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">                      
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="Firma">
       <SeznamFaktVyd>
          <FaktVyd>
             <Doklad>
                <xsl:value-of select="faktura/@ID_FAKTURA_VYDANA" />
             </Doklad>        
             <Vystaveno>
                <xsl:value-of select="faktura/@DATUM_VYSTAVENI" />
             </Vystaveno>
          </FaktVyd> 
       </SeznamFaktVyd>
   </xsl:template>   
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And i have this XML output:

```
<SeznamFaktVyd>
   <FaktVyd>
      <Doklad>1</Doklad>
      <Vystaveno>1.1.2014</Vystaveno>
   </FaktVyd>
</SeznamFaktVyd>
<SeznamFaktVyd>
   <FaktVyd>
      <Doklad>2</Doklad>
      <Vystaveno>1.2.2014</Vystaveno>
   </FaktVyd>
</SeznamFaktVyd>
```

And i want this output XML:

```
<SeznamFaktVyd>
   <FaktVyd>
      <Doklad>1</Doklad>
      <Vystaveno>1.1.2014</Vystaveno>
   </FaktVyd>
   <FaktVyd>
      <Doklad>2</Doklad>
      <Vystaveno>1.2.2014</Vystaveno>
   </FaktVyd>
</SeznamFaktVyd>
```

I want the -SeznamFaktVyd- only once ind document and -/SeznamFaktVyd- only once...
Have you any ideas please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than 1 `<Firma>` node in your xml, so if you match 'Firma' you will end up with multiple `<SeznamFaktVyd>` nodes. To group them together inside 1 root node, add a template that will start from the root and apply templates for `<Firma>` from there:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <SeznamFaktVyd>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Firma"/>
    </SeznamFaktVyd>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Firma">
    <FaktVyd>
        <Doklad>
            <xsl:value-of select="faktura/@ID_FAKTURA_VYDANA" />
        </Doklad>        
        <Vystaveno>
            <xsl:value-of select="faktura/@DATUM_VYSTAVENI" />
        </Vystaveno>
    </FaktVyd> 
    ...
```

Comment: Not run...result xml like this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SeznamFaktVyd/>

Comment: You'll have to show (a part of) your input XML, could be as simple as a missing namespace...